# How to add test-case of a route only with pathEnd

Tags: spray, spray-dsl, spray-test

I have a route

```
get {
  pathEnd {
    respondWithMediaType(`text/html`) { // XML is marshalled to `text/xml` by default, so we simply override here
      complete("[]")
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to add a test-case for this route like this

```
Get() ~> route ~> check {
    mediaType === MediaTypes.`text/html`
    responseAs[String] === "[]"
  }
```

But I am getting

```
[error]    Request was not handled
```

Can anyone tell me how to write test-case for this route? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the most simplest case work where the only thing you check is `status === StatusCodes.OK`?